# How do I Turn Off Code Graphic in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, editor

What does Pycharm call the section of the editor pane that shows the code graphic for vertical scrolling? I want to turn it off but for the life of me I can't find the setting, or even what it's called.

[image]

Comment: Do you have one of the minimap plugins installed? E.g. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275-codeglance? That's not part of core PyCharm AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, that was it.  I don't remember ever installing that but I guess I must have (?).  Is there any way that plugins can be sneaky and weave their way into Pycharm? Like a dependency from another plugin?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware.